# Internationalization version selector imputprompt

Tags: magnolia

I am following this for [internationalization document](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Internationalization) in magnolia cms 5.7.

I need to internationalize the version selector input prompt in the pagebar but cannot find the key for this value.

```
import com.vaadin.v7.ui.ComboBox;
private ComboBox versionSelector = new ComboBox();
    private Listener listener;



    public VersionSelectorViewImpl() {
        construct();
    }

    private void construct() {
        versionSelector.setVisible(false);
        versionSelector.setImmediate(true);
        versionSelector.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        versionSelector.setTextInputAllowed(false);
        versionSelector.setInputPrompt("Select a version"); //***this is the key I need ***
        versionSelector.addStyleName("version-selector");
        versionSelector.setSizeFull();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by injecting **SimpleTranslator** in the constructor:

```
            private final SimpleTranslator i18n;
        
            @Inject
            public VersionSelectorViewImpl(SimpleTranslator i18n){
                this.i18n = i18n;
                construct();
            }
        
        
            private void construct() {
                String inputPrompt = i18n.translate("module.pagebar.selectVersion");
                
                versionSelector.setInputPrompt(inputPrompt);
                ...
            }
```

and then passing the key value found in the message bundle file for each language respectively.

An example  is also found here `info.magnolia.contacts.app.field.component.ContactPreviewComponent`.